# Does it make sense to do typing for python variables since they do not catch errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am new to python typing. I declared a variable as string and deliberately assign a set into the string variable. Yet, python doesn't catches any error.

```
diff_str: str = get_set(f1, f2)
```

The question is does it make sense to do typing for python variables since they do not catch errors?

I am using python 3.7

Comment: Typing in python is useful for hinting only. This makes it more clear : [Static type checking](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/learn-how-to-use-static-type-checking-in-python-3-6-in-10-minutes-12c86d72677b)

Comment: Theses are type **annotation**. They exist for documentation and features like auto-suggestion in IDEs. They do **not** enforce the type annotated. Python remains a duck-typed language.

Comment: For Python it's just an annotation, nothing more. Third party tools can be used for checking an annotated program. PEP484 states that in its "Rationale and Goals".

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem meaningful to add those typing declarations if no enforcement is made in compiler.

Comment: There's no "compiler". It's interpreter. Many other interpreted languages use this as well. As for "doesn't seem meaningful" - I don't use such inline annotations, but specifying types for parameters and return values in docstrings gives pretty nice hints in the IDE!

Comment: I think it makes sense to add typing to function declarations. Not so much for variables.

Comment: @user3848207 IMHO annotations are sometimes meaningful as a sort of "small documentation". I use them where annotation itself is trival. If not, I prefer text in comments or docstring. That includes variables and functions.

Comment: @h4z3 you may want to check your facts - CPython IS compiled to byte-code, which is then executed by the runtime. Also there's no such thing as "an interpreted language" - a language is a set of syntaxic and grammattical rules, it's the implementation of a language that can use either native binary code compilation and linking, byte-code compilation or plain direct interpretation from the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a very dynamic language, you can add / remove / replace attributes and methods at runtime, so static type checking is indeed irrelevant. Note that the real uses for static typing (in general) is NOT "type safety" or "more robust code" but 1/ compiler optimizations and 2/ developer documentation.

As an example, C uses static typing (with compile-time typechecking), but you can freely cast anything into anything else without any compile-time error - but usually with much more dramatic results at runtime than what you'll get in Python when something goes wrong. As another example, even ADA (undoubtly the most psycho-rigid language ever when it comes to typing) didn't prevent the Ariane5 crash.

wrt/ Python, the recent introduction of type **hints** was due to demand for eventual "static" code instrumentation (including doc, IDE hints support, and possibly at some point some optimizations - but those would require a restricted implementation of the language.

Answer (score 1):

It is no actual typing, and so, it makes sense for code clarification only. And that you are accomplishing in naming ("..._str"). If you're not using an annotation aware IDE, that will track your type annotations, it is your name convention that will help you remember variable types several lines after they're defined.